# Why are the settings not showing up?

Tags: objects

[image: The settings (i dont know what they are called) on the right aren't showing up]

I have my object selected and don't know why the settings are not there. I've tried different objects and it's the same problem. Can somebody help?
Edit: I can see all the settings in the Shading tab..

Comment: That's indeed strange, looks like you have no active object although an object is selected. Can you switch to the *Scripting* workspace and type `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active` into the console. What's the return value?

Comment: Return: bpy.data.objects['SM_Apollo_Rock_LRG_03.mo']

Comment: The screenshot is cropped so top and bottom of the window aren't visible which makes it harder to estimate what is visible at all (e.g all the3d viewport header, Overlays menu etc). If Properties panel is meant try to press N to open it back.

Comment: @MrZak I assumed Laxe meant the missing property tabs. Laxe can you try to open the project through *File > Open*  and uncheck *Load UI*? Does that make any difference?

Comment: @rjg I unchecked it and now the property tabs are there!!Thank you so much :)

Comment: Tabs in Prpoerties editor could miss if one of them (e.g Scene) was pinned right after an object was deleted and no object was active. This is unexpected behaviour which was in 2.79 and somehow survived in 2.8 as well. Laxe, if you have answer please write it yourself below or ask @rjg but don't edit the question, that's not how things are working on SE.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is likely caused by pinning the data-block's properties after an object was deleted. The property tabs can be restored by unpinning.

[image: Pinned scene]

Description of the pin functionality in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/properties_editor.html#header):

> By toggling on the pin icon to the right, Blender can be told to
>   display in that editor only the currently shown data-block’s
>   properties, disregarding further selection changes. Toggle off that
>   pin to switch back to default behavior, showing active data-block’s
>   properties.

Alternatively you can also uncheck *Load UI* when opening a project through *File > Open* in Blender, which ignores all UI settings stored in the project file. This can be helpful for example when loading a project from older versions of Blender with a different UI layout.