# Properties Panel missing many options

Tags: properties

How it should look:
[image]

The above picture is a startup file that is working perfectly!

But the file which I am working on is looking strange!
And it is actually:
[image]
When it was a new file, it had all the options, but now they disappeared!

How do I fix this?

> Also when I am in `Edit Mode` it does not show assign button to assign
>   material on selected faces

Comment: If you removed the camera from the scene, it will remove options having to do with the camera.

Comment: Could it be the same problem described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155912/why-are-the-settings-not-showing-up)?

Comment: @RobertGützkow Yeah it was that! Thanks